# Using select2 addon with Ember cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, jquery-select2

I'm kind of new to Emberjs and I'm having trouble using select2 addon.

The [docs](https://istefo.github.io/ember-select-2/#/docs) were completely useless, I couldn't get a single info from there. Now I want to make the user to be able to select multiple data gathered from the database I tried using "model" in the "content" section but it's not working.

Here is the sample I took from the docs

```
{{select-2
  content=patients
  value=patients
  multiple=true
  placeholder="Choose some Pizzas"
}}
```

and my controller

```
patients: Ember.computed(function(){
  return this.store.findAll('patient')
}),
```

It sounds like I need to loop through the record from the database, either that or I need to follow a convention where the object needs to have an id, name and a description, I even tried to use "patient.name" but it won't work. I also tried to add the sample to a component "don't know why" but it made the whole app crashes and shows nothing but a white screen (no errors in the console).

Comment: ember-select-2 is deprecated in favor of [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/)

Comment: Great i'll try playing around to get it .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mentioned in comment, [ember-select2](https://github.com/iStefo/ember-select-2) is deprecated in favour of [power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select) addon. You can view great [documentation](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/multiple-selection) for all possibilities.

```
{{#power-select-multiple
  options=patients
  selected=name
  placeholder="Select some names..."
  onchange=(action (mut name))
  as |patient|
}}
  {{patient.name}}
{{/power-select-multiple}}
```

and in controller,

```
patients: Ember.computed('model',function(){
  return this.store.findAll('patient')
}),
```

Here is the [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/24dde8db8c7b412920545147fb4f386a?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for demonstration. to kick start your journey with power-select.

Comment: why did you write 'model' in the controller ?

Comment: returning data from the `store` should be done in `Route`

Comment: @ctcpip that's how I have done it in twiddle I posted in the link. But OP used  `patients` in controller, I showed that will for that too. Any how I missed to point to OP best practise always load the data in corresponding route. Thanks :)

Comment: @Haboosh Always load the required data in the route. I introduced `model` as dependant key to make sure by that time computed property runs it should get data from store